# Scala - trying to understand for-comprehension

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I'm still pretty new to Scala, and I'm trying to understand a section of code I came across:

```
for { 
  _ <- func1() 
  result <- func2() 
} yield result
```

`func1` and `func2` return different types. I'm trying to understand the first line `_ <- func1()`

It looks to me like it just calls `func1()` and then drops the result? Does `func1()` act as a gating mechanism for `func2()`? That is, if `func1()` throws an exception, then `func2()` does not get run? But otherwise, any return value from `func1()` is thrown away?

Comment: That code is equivalent to `func1().flatMap(_ => func2())` what does `flatMap` means depends on the result type of both functions, assuming something like `Either` then yes, your supposition is correct, it won't execute `func2` if `func1` returns a `Left` - However, in general, `flatMap` always means sequence, so yeah this ensures `func1` happens before `func2`

Comment: In this case, both `func1()` and `func2()` produce futures, so am I correct in understanding that it will only yield result when both functions are successful futures?

Comment: Yes, this code says that `func2()` won't run until `func1()` finishes and only if it finished successfully.